# Is there any alternative to Universal-linking in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, ios9, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Okay I have been trying day long to figure deep linking and universal linking. 
I am trying to design an app which has a deep link as "bunty" .

So I have a web link as http://www.bunty.org & if I click on this URL in my iphone it would result in opening myapp. And if not it would open the url in Safari or any other browser.

Till now my search results direct me towards Universal Linking . So is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do like going via deep linking only?

Comment: your link to your app would be more like `bunty://` that would launch your app from safari.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're saying is that you want to deeplink into your app with the base URL. Unfortunately for universal links on iOS, this behavior is expected - Universal links only work from a different domain. So, you won't be able to open your app through the root domain.

You can use universal links through a non-root domain. One way to make this easier is to use [branch](https://branch.io/) to make deep linking easier - it's totally free and you can make custom redirects for individual links and platforms, and pass data through install.

As of iOS9.2, URI schemes are deprecated, so going with Universal links is probably your best option. If you use Branch, you can also set up a custom domain (not the same as your root domain) with [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) to use for your Universal links.

Comment: Can you please suggest a more detail procedure?

Comment: Sure thing - actually all the steps to set up for Universal links with Branch are found here: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/branch_universal_links/ios/. You'll have to set up an account from the branch.io main page first first and follow the steps here (it's completely free and pretty fast):https://dev.branch.io/#getting-started